# Where should I store custom permissions for my web app

Tags: configuration, permissions, xml-configuration

I'm wondering where is the ideal place to store custom permissions in my web applications.

For example I have the following permissions:

AdminPermission
ReadPermission
WritePermission

At the moment I store these in the static utilities class as the constant string type objects.

Thank you

Comment: Hey, no, they are the permissions that will be applied to the roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go for a database approach with enums referencing records in xml config.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I guess you are talking about a Java app. You could try to externalize these resource in files, like in Tomcat (e.g. `tomcat-users.xml`).

Comment: Hey, thx for the reply, no I'm speaking about the .net web app with a c# front end...